# Consulta SQL datos correctos

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, model, model-view-controller

vengo con otra duda.

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM proyectos INNER JOIN empresa ON proyectos.id_usuario=$id_usuario && proyectos.id_proyecto=$id_proyectoA
```

Esta consulta me envia los datos de empresa y proyecto por medio de un join para poder imprimirlos en la vista, pero tanto en MysQl me envia todos los datos de la tabla, o sea, es como si no filtrara por id_usuario e id_proyectoA si no que hace la consulta y trae todo lo que esta en esas 2 tablas.

Mi duda es que podría estar mal en esta consulta para que solo me envíe los datos que estoy filtrando.

De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: $id_usuario <- esto que es? si es una clausula de join, no estaria bien...

Comment: Es la variable que contiene el id del usuario, pero ya lo resolví haciendo el filtro más especifico añadiendo el id de la empresa para que solo se filtre el que necesito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cierto solo escribí que lo solucioné, mil disculpas aquí el SQL

`SELECT * FROM proyectos INNER JOIN empresa ON proyectos.id_usuario=$id_usuario and proyectos.id_proyecto=$id_proyectoA and empresa.id_empresa=$id_empresaA`

Solo hice más estricto el filtro puesto que la consulta era muy ambigua incluso ara el Mysql, entonces incluí el id de la empresa en este caso para poder obtener el resultado correcto, espero le sirva a alguien más esta solución.

Comment: Es mas... como le pasabas los parametros? que tenian los parametros? y porque estas haciendo una consulta que estaria mal, porque estas incluyendo las clausulas que deberian estar en el where, dentro del join, y cual es la condicion de join de esas tablas? asi como esta, esta consulta puede llegar a devolver cualquier cosa...

Comment: Pues gracias por tus comentarios, esta consulta como está, devuelve exactamente lo que necesito y el problema estaba en la consulta directamente no en el resto del código por lo que la solución que acabo de poner es correcta, y ya que nuevamente digo el problema estaba en la consulta y se resolvió de esa manera simplemente lo tomo como resuelto, de igual forma nuevamente gracias por tu primer comentario, pásala bien.

Comment: Tene en cuenta, que a tu consulta le falta una condicion de join (esta haciendo un producto cartesiano) y ademas, lo que pusiste en el join, iria en el where, porque no son las condiciones de union de las tablas. Ademas, deberias explicar tu problema y tu solucion completas... si no, tu respuesta es solo codigo. mira por favor [answer]

Comment: Claro, entiendo que hayas solucionado tu problema, pero tene en cuenta que el sitio no es solo para tu problema, es para que tu problema y tu solucion le sirvan a alguien mas en el futuro. En este caso, tu problema no es claro (le faltan varias cosas) y tu solucion, aunque te funciona, tiene defectos de forma. En este caso, te recomendaria borrar la pregunta, ya que en realidad la tendriamos que cerrar como no reproducible o poco clara.